# Twilio always returns callstatus as 'completed' in statuscallback

Tags: callback, twilio, status

I am making a call using Twilio using the following code

```
$call = $client->account->calls->create ($twilioPhoneNumber,
$customerPhoneNumber,       // The number of the phone receiving call
$url, 
$options); // The URL Twilio will request when the call is answered
```

In the options, I have the following parameters:

```
$options =  array('StatusCallback'=>'twilioStatusCallback.php',
 'IfMachine'=>'Hangup', 'FallbackUrl'=>'fallBack.php','Timeout'=>'15');
```

If the call is answered, and the Twilio menu goes through correctly, there is no problem.

But if the call is not answered or busy, Twilio still returns the call status as 'completed' to twilioStatusCallback.php

How can I get a correct busy or no-answer status instead?

Thanks.

Comment: anyone figure this out? It's still a problem as of Mar 2016

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

When you're [making calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls), the `completed` event is fired when the call is completed, regardless of the status.

You can create custom actions while tracking call status based upon the [transitions between call state](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-do-i-track-the-call-status-of-an-outbound-call).

Comment: Sorry but there is no difference in the data you get when the user take the call and then let it go up to time-out or when the user don't take the call...